# RPi 2 isnt booting, Green and Red light ON

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-2, boot-issues, noobs

I have Rpi 2 model B v1.1 for a week. I tried some cirquits with GPIO pins. One day i made a simple button cirquit. It worked well. But few minutes ago Rpi crashed, i powered it off. When i power it on, it doesn't boot. Red and Green lights were on. No video output. Processor isn't heating up

I tried more SD cards, formating SD card and rewriting NOOBS and Rasbian image. But Rpi isnt booting. S think, SD card is fine, because i tried it in friend Rpi and it works well.

Please someone help

Images of cirquit:(the resistor is 330Ohm)[image]

Comment: Did the Pi crash a few minutes after making the button circuit or a few days after.  If a few minutes you may have blown the polyfuse which may recover after a day or so.  Could you add details of the button circuit and a photo to your question?

Comment: Pi crash a few minutes after making the button cirquit, but the cirquit worked well. There is image of cirquit - http://raspi.tv/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/RasPi.TV-interrupt1_bb.jpg

Comment: That is what you intended to do.  A photo will show what you actually did.

Comment: Or even better, a schematic including clear labeling of which pins you connected to.

Comment: I'm trying to remember my high school electronics classes, so forgive me if I'm mistaken, but is it that you're trying to light the LED? If so, I don't think the resistors should be in parallel.

Comment: I can see nothing in that circuit which would have damaged the Pi.  Did you do anything else?

Comment: I didn't se anything dangerous too.  I only have wired oficial PI camera. I didnt make anything else.